# HttpClient hangs for large request

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone-8.1, windows-mobile

I have an issue in an app developed for Windows Phone 8.1, where its working just fine, but in Windows Mobile 10 it gets stuck on GetAsync. It doesn't throw an exception or anything, just gets stuck there waiting endlessly. The content-length of the response is 22014030 bytes.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
             return await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried reading it as a stream, but as soon as i try to read the content body nothing happens anymore.

The code that calls this function is declared as:

```
 public async Task<List<APIJsonObject>> DownloadJsonObjectAsync()
    {
        string jsonObjectString = await DownloadStringAsync(Constants.URL);

        if (jsonObjectString != null && jsonObjectString.Length >= 50)
        {
            List<APIJsonObject> result = await Task.Run<List<APIJsonObject>>(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APIJsonObject>>(jsonObjectString));

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls this code.

Comment: 20.9 MiB is a lot of data to get over a mobile connection. Especially if the high speed contingent was used up already and you are down to something like UMTS. But yes, we need the calling code too. Otherwise it is hard to tell if there is a mistake in your Multitasking or Mutlithreading Logic.

Comment: Is there any point in your code that blocks, like with `.Result`?

Comment: There is no such calls. Only async/await.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is blocking is because you are getting a huge response (20.9MB) which the `HttpClient` will try to download before giving you a result.

However, you can tell the `HttpClient` to return a result as soon as the response headers are read from the server, which means you get a `HttpResponseMessage` faster. To do this, you will need to pass `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` as a parameter to the `SendRequestAsync` method of the `HttpClient`

Here is how:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), url))
    {
        using (var response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
        {
          //Read the response here using a stream for example if you are downloading a file
          //get the stream to download the file using: response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Everytime i try to access the content stream, it blocks.
i tried by copying small fragments at a time, like 200 bytes:
`using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        {
                            await contentStream.ReadAsync(a, 0, a.Length);
                        }`

But the call to ReadAsync never returns.

Comment: @Stayfrosty555 just to be sure, did you try HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead? Also are you calling it from the UI thread?

Comment: yes. I tried making a new windows phone 8.1 application to have a clean solution. I made a button with this attached to the click event handler. https://paste.ee/p/l7nWs if i set a breakpoint after stream.ReadByte(), i will never reach it.

Comment: @Stayfrosty555 ok, have you tried accessing that resource with your browser or Postman? And what happens if you try to use a different URL?

Can you also show the code calling `DownloadJsonObjectAsync` ?

Comment: It works flawlessly to download same url on Windows 10 (without mobile :)), and as shown shown in the paste I can't even get it to work without removing any calling code that might interfere. Other URLs works on Windows 10 mobile, but they much smaller in content size.

Comment: @Stayfrosty555 in your paste, I just noticed you are using ReadAsStreamAsync() instead of ReadAsInputStreamAsync().